# make appearing a flexbox on hover

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hover, display

I need some help with a css issue. I'm actually trying to make an animated checked-button with a double animation effet. You can see what I'm aiming at here:

https://youtu.be/rMDGeAUQ0Wc

I'm working on the appearing of the button from the right side. I decided to use flexbox associated with a hover feature so I can make appear the button on hover, but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexbox-3 {
  display: none;
}

.flexbox-container: hover+flexbox-3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">

  <div class="flexbox-1">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox-2">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox-3">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Does anyone can help?

Cheers

Comment: `.flexbox-container: hover` - that space does not belong there. You do not want to look for an element that has the _tag name_ `hover` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    .flexbox-container:hover > .flexbox-3 {
        display: block;
     }
```

but I think that animation will not work due to `display:none block`. I would prefer you to write the code this way.

```
 .flexbox-3 {
        position: relative;
        right: -30%;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .flexbox-container:hover > .flexbox-3 {
        right: 0;
      }
```

if you want to move `.flexbox-2` try this CSS. I add `tranform: translate`

```
     .flexbox-container {
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      .flexbox-3 {
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0;
        right: -30%;
        transition: 0.5s;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      .flexbox-2 {
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .flexbox-container:hover .flexbox-3 {
        right: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
      .flexbox-container:hover .flexbox-2 {
        transform: translateX(-30px);
      }
```

Comment: I tried that one. The thing with this is that when you push the flexbox 3 out of the flexbox container the 2nd flexbox don't move to the far right of the flexbox container.

Comment: @monCompte I added some codes. Try that

Comment: I've applied the position and right property to the flexbox 2 just the same as the flexbox 3 and added an hover just like for the flexbox 3 as well. It seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your CSS
Try this

```
.flexbox-container:hover .flexbox-3 {
    display: block
}
```

however the animation will not work here because animate does not work with the display property

Comment: Please edit your answer rather than commenting on it.